# How to write an if/and statement in google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to write an if/and statement based on two different drop down lists.  Is it possible to write something with the logic below? The "if &&" statement does not work properly, but will work just fine with a single "if" statement.  I understand the is a bit of code, but this is the only way I can show exactly what is happening.

```
    function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();

  var containerSizeList = app.createListBox().setId('containerSizeList').setName('containerSizeList');
  containerSizeList.addItem("20ft Long");
  containerSizeList.addItem("40ft Long");

  var loadingStyleList = app.createListBox().setId('loadingStyleList').setName('loadingStyleList');
  loadingStyleList.addItem("On Pallets");
  loadingStyleList.addItem("Floor Loaded");

    var tenPalletPanel = app.createHorizontalPanel().setId('tenPalletPanel').setVisible(true);
    var tenPalletLabel = app.createLabel('10 Pallets Available').setId('tenPalletLabel');
    var twentyPalletPanel = app.createHorizontalPanel().setId('twentyPalletPanel').setVisible(false);
    var twentyPalletLabel = app.createLabel('20 Pallets Available').setId('twentyPalletLabel');
    var loadingNotePanel = app.createHorizontalPanel().setId('loadingNotePanel').setVisible(false);
    var loadingNoteLabel = app.createLabel('Note: Only certain products may be floor loaded')
    .setId('loadingNoteLabel');

    var containerGrid = app.createGrid(1, 2);
    containerGrid.setWidget(0, 0, containerSizeList);
    containerGrid.setWidget(0, 1, loadingStyleList);

    var handlerJ = app.createServerClickHandler('palletChangeMe'); 
    containerSizeList.addChangeHandler(handlerJ);
    loadingStyleList.addChangeHandler(handlerJ);
    handlerJ.addCallbackElement(containerGrid);       

  app.add(containerGrid);
  app.add(tenPalletPanel);
  tenPalletPanel.add(tenPalletLabel);
  app.add(twentyPalletPanel);
  twentyPalletPanel.add(twentyPalletLabel);
  app.add(loadingNotePanel);
  loadingNotePanel.add(loadingNoteLabel);

  return app;
}

function palletChangeMe(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  if (e.parameter.containerSizeList == "40ft Long" && e.parameter.loadingStyleList == "On Pallets"){
    app.getElementById('tenPalletPanel').setVisible(false);
    app.getElementById('twentyPalletPanel').setVisible(true);
    app.getElementById('loadingNotePanel').setVisible(false);
}

  return app;
}
```

Comment: Where is the callbackElement  for the handler?

Comment: This was the issue.  I updated the code so it works now.  Thx again Serge.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of:

```
if (e.parameter.containerSizeList == "20ft Long"){
  and if (e.parameter.loadingStyleList == "On Pallets"){
```

Should be:

```
if (e.parameter.containerSizeList == "20ft Long" && e.parameter.loadingStyleList == "On Pallets"){
```

Note: `&&` means logical AND. [Read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) about logical operators at MDN.

and you need to remove last `}` in each if statement, so final code would be like:

```
if (e.parameter.containerSizeList == "20ft Long" && e.parameter.loadingStyleList == "On Pallets"){
    app.getElementById('tenPalletPanel').setVisible(true);
    app.getElementById('twentyPalletPanel').setVisible(false);
}

if (e.parameter.containerSizeList == "40ft Long" && e.parameter.loadingStyleList == "On Pallets"){
    app.getElementById('tenPalletPanel').setVisible(false);
    app.getElementById('twentyPalletPanel').setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Hello, antyrat.  For some reason this is not working in google apps script.  Could there be a slightly different way to do this in google apps script?  I noticed this is how it is done in javascript, but wondering if GAS has a little different way to do an if/and statment.  I made sure my } were in the correct place.

Comment: @user1833055 GAS is just API written in JS for google services so there is no other way to write if/and statements, you need to make sure that your `containerSizeList` and `loadingStyleList` have exact values with you checked. I.e characters case, spaces, etc. Just try to add `console.log(containerSizeList);console.log(loadingStyleList);` and see in browser console what happens + check if there is no other errors in your script

Comment: I am not sure why it is not working.  I have made sure that all of the characters are correct. However, I have noticed when I use "e.parameter.containerSizeList == "40ft Long"" or "e.parameter.loadingStyleList == "On Pallets"" by itself, the if statement works.  But when I use "e.parameter.containerSizeList == "40ft Long" && e.parameter.loadingStyleList == "On Pallets"" the "if &&" statement does not work anymore.  Do you have anyother suggestions?

Comment: @user1833055 ok please look at this jsFiddle demo. It works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/antyrat/caXu6/

Comment: I have edited my original code I posted so you can see exactly how my function works.  Could you take a look at this and see if you can see anything that is incorrect with my function or any other code.  As I mentioned before.  It works just fine with a single if statement, but stops working with I use the "if &&" statement.  Could there be a possible bug?

Comment: Now that the logger is working again in handler functions I'd suggest you use it to check what the e.parameter returns : `Logger.log(e.parameter.containerSizeList + ' &&  ' + e.parameter.loadingStyleList)`

Comment: @user1833055 what console output?

Comment: @Sergeinsas I was missing the callbackhandler.  I updated my code to include handlerJ.addCallbackElement(containerGrid) thanks a million. Antyrat, what do you mean by console output?

Comment: @user1833055 I mean fo example google chrome console https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console

Comment: oh yes.  I am using google chrome.  I think everything is all good now.  Thanks for your help and patience antyrat.