# How to sort, filter and replace value in google apps script based on header row values?

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets, filtering, columnsorting

I'm new to google apps script and stuck with a problem. I do this process on a daily basis and was wondering if I could automate this in order to save time.
This is what I want to do:

Step 1: Select column with header "C". Replace all "?" by "w". Replace all "1" by "v"

Step 2: Sort column with header "company" by A-Z

Step 3: Sort column with header "priority" by A-Z. If column with header "priority" is not found, move to next step (sometime priority column is not present)

Step 4: Sort column with header "C" by Z-A

Step 5: Filter column with header "C" for blanks

Step 6: Sort column with header "OV comment" by A-Z

Step 7: Sort column with header "PV" by Z-A

Step 8: Filter column with header "C" for all

Please refer to the following link to see a sample file:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bp1jcb3Ex6cdURbU9ScVJO_gTVyyeskojn1_S97-fPk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you started writing the script? If so, show us what you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. Looking around here at Stack Overflow would pretty much have what you need (along with a little bit of googling).

1. [Get column by name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36346918/4625829). [Search](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13327069/4625829) and [Replace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26157489/4625829) your specified characters (possibly simpler if you use [`replaceText()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#replacetextsearchpattern-replacement)).
2. [Sort alphabetically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35563828/4625829) (refer here for any other type of sorting).
3. See #2. Use an [`if` condition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13894057/4625829).
4. See #2.
5. [Filter for blank/empty cells](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29659313/4625829).
6. See #2.
7. See #2.
8. See #5.

Comment: With all that said, if you were hoping for an actual working code to be provided, unfortunately, Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service.